# Hide console window while making Tkinter executable for mac os usind pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I'm making executable for mac using `pyinstaller`. Having the same problem, a console window pops up along with GUI. Please let me know, how can I hide the console window for MAC OS when GUI is in running state using `pyinstaller`.

I have tried the following commands but it doesn't work for me:

```
pyinstaller --windowed --onefile app.py
```

```
pyinstaller --noconsole --windowed --onefile app.py
```

I want to make an executable app using `pyinstaller` for MAC OS which contains tkInter program.

Comment: Can you post your script code (or a simplified version of it including your window initialization code).

Comment: `-w` has always worked for me.

Comment: with script code did you mean spec file?

Comment: For mac i have used      
"pyinstaller -w onefile app.py"
"pyinstaller --windowed --onefile app.py"
"pyinstaller --noconsole --windowed --onefile app.py"

but all these didn't worked

Comment: Relevant [`[python] [pyinstaller] hide console`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ayes+is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D+%5Bpyinstaller%5D+hide+console)